# 19.10 Kubuntu Enable menu bar on second monitor

Tags: kde, plasma

I've got an additional monitor attached, aside of my laptop's. The system's Kubuntu 19.10, minimal installation.

The menu bar appears only on the laptop's monitor, even if the program's on the additional one.
[image]
I'd like to have it cloned on the second screen as well. How do I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To [add a new panel](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Panels) either click on the desktop toolbox button and select **Add Panel** or open the context (right click) menu on the desktop and select **Add Panel** from the menu. **Default Panel** make a Panel with all of the default widgets (launcher, pager, tasks, system tray, clock, etc.), which looks like what you want.

If you can't create it on the second monitor, create a second panel of the first monitor then drag-and-drop it to the second monitor.